# How to test getElementsByClassName method with unit-testing?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I want to test a function which add a classname to a div container when there are more than 7 pages. But don't get it worked.

Tried with spyOn, but no result.

The constructor

```
constructor($document, $element) {
  this.$document = $document;
  this.$element = $element;
}
```

onInit function

```
$onInit() {
const listPages = this.element.children;
const totalPages = listPages.length;

if (totalPages> 7) {
  this.$document[0].getElementsByClassName('test-container')[0].className += ' test';
}
}
```

I tried this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
this.documentSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('$document', ['getElementsByClassName']);
this.elementSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('$element', ['find']);
});


fit('should add class test when styles contain atleast 7 steps', () => {
    let stepPage = new stepPageController(this.documentSpy, this.elementSpy);
    stepPage.element = {
        children: [
            { step: ['current'] },
            { step: ['step2'] },
            { step: ['step3'] },
            { step: ['step4'] },
            { step: ['step5'] },
            { step: ['step6'] },
            { step: ['step7'] },
            { step: ['step8'] }
        ]
    };

    const element = angular.element(this.$document[0].body).append('<div class="test-container"></div>');
    spyOn(stepPage.$document[0], 'getElementsByClassName').and.returnValue(element);

    // When
    stepPage.$onInit();

    // Then
    expect(stepPage.$document[0].getElementsByClassName('test-container')[0].className).toBe('test');
});
```

but get this as error:  TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Do you know if the error being thrown from the spyOn function or the expect? Or the assignment of `element`

Comment: @ajmeese7 no, can't replicate from where..

Comment: Can you try commenting out various stages to see if you can narrow down where the error could be coming from?